# Can Verification Java API in Digital Persona One Touch run w/o RTE?

Tags: java, verification, fingerprint, biometrics

Does this code require the Digital Persona One Touch RTE (Runtime environment) to work?:

```
DPFPVerification verifier  = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();
```

If so, is there another way to verify Digital Persona SampleFeatures (serialized) against a Digital Persona Template (serialized) using only the dpfp JARs?

Reason: We plan to have our DPFP verifier on a Web Service provided by TIBCO.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I get a Java JNI exception with this sample test main code:

```
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPFeatureSet;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPFeatureSetFactory;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPGlobal;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPTemplate;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPTemplateFactory;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.verification.DPFPVerification;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.verification.DPFPVerificationResult;


public class Main {

    /**
     * fingerScanTemplate is from WC DB
     * sample is from the WS input parameters
     */
    public boolean performVerification(byte[] fingerScanTemplate, byte[] sampleFeatures) {
            DPFPTemplateFactory templateFactory         = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory();
            DPFPFeatureSetFactory featureSetFactory     = DPFPGlobal.getFeatureSetFactory();
            DPFPVerification      verifier                          = DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();

            // Deserialize template & sampleFeature
            DPFPTemplate deserializedTemplate = templateFactory.createTemplate(fingerScanTemplate);
            DPFPFeatureSet features = featureSetFactory.createFeatureSet(sampleFeatures);

            //Compare the feature set with the template, based on which finger was captured
            DPFPVerificationResult result = null;
            result = verifier.verify(features, deserializedTemplate);

            return result != null && result.isVerified();
         }



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().performVerification(null, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you should not need some sort of RTE. I do know that I had to have the One Touch SDK installed because it runs a windows service called Biometric scanning or something similar.  The main problem I see with your code is that:

```
DPFPVerificationResult result = null;

result = verifier.verify(features, deserializedTemplate);
```

Needs to be:

```
DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result result = new DPFP.Verification.Verification.Result();

verifier.verify(features, template, ref result );
```

At least that is what got my code to start verifying correctly. I also had to fix a programmer's mistake in creating the FeatureSet which needs to be done like this:

```
DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Verification);
```

I have a feeling you are using an older SDK than I am but maybe this will help out some.